# Is it better to have one table with 100's of columns or multiple tables that can be joined together

Tags: sql, database

I have a relational database that I am going to be restructuring and one of the tables has over 100 columns in it. To me that seems a little much, but I don't know the best practices. This table is queried a lot and needs to be fast and about half the time all columns are needed. My question is should I split this table into smaller tables that can be joined together when needed or keep it as is?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It depends. Normalizing the table will be a good (and popular) idea which will gain you many benefits but you really should not be religious about it: in some cases (for performance) keeping a table denormalized makes sense (be aware of the disadvantages). Can't really answer your question on what to do in this case in an authorative way: it depends on too many factors, none of which are listed here.

Comment: There isn't a [real] answer to the question: it all depends...on your data model. Does the entity in question actually *have* 100+ attributes or are there other entities trapped inside trying to get out? The topic of E-R modelling and database design is better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: The table in question represents an invoice and it does have over 100 attributes. my question is more trying to figure out the best practices. (btw thanks for the link)

Comment: I know this question has been asked before, but it's hard to write a search string that finds it.

Comment: One thing to watch out for is database limits. E.g. MySQL limits row size to 65K bytes (not including TEXT and BLOB column contents).

Comment: An invoice with 100 attributes?  You're not counting the line items as attributes, are you?

Comment: No the the Invoice lines have their own table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it'd be better to leave it as one big table. Since the queries are typically returning all columns, I presume inserts also insert to all columns. Splitting it into multiple tables would potentially make inserts a nightmare. Plus, having one big table saves the DB from having to do a lot of work to put a bunch of small tables back together on every query.

Answer (score 0):

You mileage will vary depending on your specific conditions and could vary according to your specific DBMS. Try both ways and measure.

If I needed all the columns most of the time, I would guess that keeping everything in one table would be more efficient than joining multiple tables. I have had cases where I de-normalized data to decrease the number of tables, which made the queries much faster.